# .NET webservice issue?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf, web-services

My svc webservice show following schema location if i deploy in my local system.

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.168.2.22/FileDownload/TransferService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.168.2.22/FileDownload/TransferService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

If i deploy the same webservice in live server, it takes computer name in place of ip. How can i correct it?

live server wsdl code is as follows.

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://user-01/FileDownload/TransferService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://user-01/FileDownload/TransferService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: why is it a problem? do you get an error?

Comment: i am not getting an error. But i want ip in the position of user-01. is there any solution. thanks in Advance.

Comment: But why do you want that? If it is not a problem why are you trying to fix it? That is why I'm asking.

Comment: ok. when i am generate code for iPhone using http://sudzc.com/Default.aspx?. it shows some error.

Comment: Ok, so what you are asking for is not really correct. I don't know how to solve your problem, but people should be more likely to be able to help you if you present what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [httpGetUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicemetadatabehavior.httpgeturl.aspx) on the ServiceMetadataBehavior